# "Who should be ashamed is your wife" is this ungrammatical? Why?

Tags: phrase-usage, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

Is this usage common?

Example:

> In your case, who should be ashamed is your wife.

I ask because 99% of the results in [Google Books](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22who%20should%20be%20ashamed%20is%22&biw=1280&bih=938&tbm=bks&ei=SjsrVtiIO4K70gSmzbSgDw&start=0&sa=N&dpr=1) are "the one who should..." or "the person who should."

Maybe *...who should...* is an incomplete phrase?

Comment: It's not common or "natural", and it's of questionable "legality".  In this case, at least, the 99% is right.

Comment: +1 for an interesting grammar question. Don't get that many of those round here nowadays!

Comment: Perhaps "She who should be ashamed is your wife"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This use of *who* (as a subject relative pronoun without an antecedent noun phrase) is almost obsolete. It was so used in older English, and survives in a few proverbs and quotations, such as:

> Who steals my purse steals trash. (William Shakespeare, *Othello*)

But it is likely to confuse people if you use it today.

**Edit:** Oddly, *what* is still used in this way, eg

> What annoys me is the traffic.

Comment: I would argue that the use of "that which" with "what" is growing, not declining.

Comment: Hmmm, is it? *Be careful who you choose*, *Ask who you like*, *You can invite who you want*, *Who you date is up to you*, *Who you select is who you'll get* ....

Comment: @Araucaria: I said _subject_ relative pronoun. All those are the object of  the relative clause.

Comment: Quite right, didn't read carefully enough!

Answer (score 4):

You are right. ***Who*** does not work as the subject of a verb unless it is interrogative.

One can ask ***Who should be ashamed?*** Or *who* can be a relative pronoun, as in ***The person who should be ashamed is...***

Even in informal conversation *who* always sounds a bit awkward as the subject of the verb, though it is sometimes used.

Comment: But *who* is the subject of a verb.  Actually *who* is the subject of the clause "who should be ashamed."  The question is why the clause doesn't work as the subject of the sentence.  It works as a nominative complement:  "Your wife is who should be ashamed."  Analog clauses with a different pronoun work as the subject:  "What I want to know is simple."

Comment: "Who", "that", "which", and probably a few others are not general-purpose pronouns, and cannot be freely substituted for the person/thing they identify.  I suppose there's a book somewhere that explains this, but the online dictionaries are sadly unclear about this, and most people rely on intuitively "just knowing" the special rules involved.

Comment: Ambiguity of interrogative vs. declarative would be a reason to avoid opening the sentence with a noun clause "Who...", but here the sentence opens with the prepositional phrase, "In your case...".  It sounds okay to my ear with this "clue", and in a technical sense anyway avoids being ungrammatical.

Comment: @hardmath: I think you're right. When I saw the title of the OP's question, I thought "that sentence sounds crazy", but when I read the question body, with the "In your case", it suddenly sounded mostly fine to me. (But it seems like we're in the minority here.)